# Grails 2.3.0 and IntelliJ 12

Tags: grails, intellij-idea, grails-2.3

Has anyone been able to make IntelliJ 12 work with Grails 2.3.0.

When I try to create a project I get the following message:

**"create-app test"Error: Could not find or load main class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter**

Answer (score 5):

From [grails.org](http://grails.org/news/1288035):

> We are aware that the IDEs will require some updates to work with
>   Grails 2.3.0. If you plan to use 2.3.0 soon, please use the Intellij
>   IDEA EAPs and latest GGTS milestone releases which include updates to
>   work with Grails 2.3.0